# How to stop intellij-idea from removing white spaces at end of text lines in my file?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using 2018.1.5 community edition of intellij editor to edit a plain text file.

I am not using a project. I start it, on Linux as follows:

```
  idea.sh  my_file.mpl
```

where my_file.mpl is plain text file.

And this works well, except for one big problem.

I need to have an empty space at end of some lines.  i.e. after the line character on some line in the file, I insert some white. I see the space is there, by doing `View->Active editor->Show White spaces`. I can see the small tiny dotts, showing there are white space character at end of line.

But as soon as I save the file, these white spaces are removed from end of line.

This causes a problem for me (for other reason, when this file is read by another app).

Is there an option to tell it intellij NOT to remove white spaces after the last character on the line?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Go to File->Settings->Editor->General and under Other, set the drop down next to Strip trailing spaces on Save to whatever you wish. For future reference, you can press Ctrl-Shift-A and type a search term to find any menu command or setting very quickly. In this case, "trailing spaces" or "strip trailing spaces" works really well.

Comment: set the drop down next to Strip trailing spaces on Save to whatever you wish >> What to set ?

Comment: @Pratik There are three choices: Modified Lines, All, and Nonel. You should pick one based on the behavior you want.

Comment: Please provide solution to user. Its confusing for people which value to select. He asked **How to stop intellij-idea from removing white spaces at end of text lines in my file?** that means there can be only 1 option.

Comment: @Pratik There are three different options, two of which can be appropriate to answer this question. I can't know which one fits what every reader of this page wants, so I won't edit my question. If you are confused about which option to pick for your particular situation, you should post a new question with a link to this one to show you have done some research.

Comment: With PyCharm 2020 this is slightly different: File->Settings->Editor->General (there is no "Other" tab or section), and then scroll down to "Save Files" section, where the drop-down is.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler You should post an answer for future visitors that are using a newer version of PyCharm.

Answer (score 23):

Newer PyCharm (2020 and beyond) have slightly different answer than [Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51528005/4955498)'s.

Go to File->Settings->Editor->General, and then scroll down to *Save Files* section. The drop down *Strip trailing spaces on Save for:* is there. You can select **None** if you don't want any stripping in no circumstances.

Here is an image showing the setting:
[image: Image describing the location of the drop-down]

Answer (score 5):

I had my `.editorconfig` and I have used `trim_trailing_whitespace=true`. So that was the issue. This is what I did to fix the issue.

```
[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace=false
```

Answer (score 4):

If changing the settings in "Editor > General > Save Files" doesn't work, the below might be useful...

There is a discussion [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000685110-I-DON-T-want-trailing-withe-spaces-removed-on-save-) about a possible bug (or at least confusing scenario) where you have set "Strip trailing spaces on Save for"=None and you still get stripping of trailing spaces, as I did. The comment by Oksana Chumak worked for me - namely, I unticked "Enable EditorConfig Support" in Settings > Editor > Code Style. This seems to allow a config file ".editorconfig" to be used which overrides some settings - also see Andriy Bazanov's answer, quoted below...

> NOTE: If you have .editorconfig file in your project, such option can
> also be controlled via that file. This file can provide more granular
> control over what files are affected by those settings.
>
> Settings from .editorconfig file will OVERWRITE IDE settings (the
> whole nature of such files), so if you have such files in your project
> and such instruction there, you will have to either disable the
> EditorConfig for this project or disable plugin completely (if you do
> not care about it at all).

Comment: It was the editor config. Thanks for the post.

Comment: this was driving me nuts

Answer (score 1):

So here's what worked for me. I wanted intellij to keep trimming whitespaces but to keep the whitespace on blank lines.

First like [@Michael-Veksler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4955498/michael-veksler) suggested, I changed intellij's default removal on save.

But it kept trimming the trailing whitespace, that was because in my `.editorconfig` file I had a `trim_trailing_whitespace` config turned on. So now I've set `trim_trailing_whitespace = false`.

Lastly, because I still wanted the editor to trim the trailing whitespaces, just not on blank lines I've added to my `.eslintrc.js` file the following setting:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  rules: {
    ...
    'no-trailing-spaces': [2, { "skipBlankLines": true }]
  }
}
```

And now lint-fix on save just takes care of it